# link_to for a button that consists of multiple child divs nested inside?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a button that consists of multiple divs inside of it for presentation purposes.  Is it possible to declare a link_to for this using Ruby on Rails 3 and jQuery.js and rails.js?

Here is my button with the visual elements completed:

```
<span id="navButton" class="navButton">
  <span class="imageBorderOverlay"></span>
  <span class="navButtonImage"><img src="/images/a.jpg"></span>
  <span class="navButtonText">
    <span class="navButtonTextBackground">Click Me!</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Here is my current link_to command that I am using separately (for testing) that works:
`<%= link_to "navButton", navA_path(:format => :js), :remote => true, :id => "aPanel" %>`

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a block to link_to, so you could do this:

```
<%= link_to navA_path(:format => :js), :remote => true, :id => "aPanel" do %>
  <span id="navButton" class="navButton">
    <span class="imageBorderOverlay"></span>
    <span class="navButtonImage"><img src="/images/a.jpg"></span>
    <span class="navButtonText">
      <span class="navButtonTextBackground">Click Me!</span>
    </span>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

*If your are using rails 2.3 remove the = sign from the erb block on the first line*